# Resolvent estimates for Laplacians on directed graphs

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, spectral-graph-theory, functional-calculus

Let us consider a directed and weighted graph $G$ with $N = |G|$ nodes. Denote the corresponding (weighted) adjacency matrix by $W \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}_{\geq 0}$ and let $D$ be the diagonal in-degree matrix with non-zero entries $D_{ii} = \sum_j W_{ij}$.

The (generically not normal) directed graph Laplacian is given as

$$L = D - W. $$

Some generic statements about the spectrum of $L$ [are possible](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.02605); it is e.g. known that each eigenvalue has non-negative real part.

Do generic norm-resolvent inequalities of the type

$$\left\|\frac{1}{L-z}\right\|\leq f(z)$$

exist for some (real valued) function $z$? Are similar inequalities known?